# Cards in bootstrap overlapping

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]

My cards in bootstrap are showing responsiveness at first but when I reduce the size of the window these cards start to overlap.

[image]

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto my-auto">
      <div class="card border-secondary mb-3">

        <div class="card-header">Habitación 1</div>
        <div class="card-body">

          <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio-hab1" id="btnradio1-hab1" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="btnradio1-hab1">ON</label>
          
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio-hab1" id="btnradio2-hab1" autocomplete="off" checked>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="btnradio2-hab1">OFF</label>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100" style="margin-top: 3%;">1 día</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100" style="margin-top: 3%;">2 días</button>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does anybody know the reason of this behaviour? Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: I copied your code 4 times to get 4 cards, and also added ```<div class="row">``` ```</div>``` at the start and end of your code. It looks good to me.

Comment: @seantsang are you using chrome? and are you minimizing the screen at the maximum?